# Formatting A ManyToManyField in to boxes with Django

Tags: python, html, django

I am having trouble with formatting. Here's what my code looks like right now:

[image]

As you can see I have a product field and a price field for each one of those products. How can I get it so that the product and price are in separate boxes like everything else?

Here's my code:

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    product = models.ManyToManyField('Product', null =True)


    def get_products(self):
        return "<br />".join("%s --- $%s" % (p.products, p.price_for_each_item) for p in self.product.all())
    get_products.allow_tags = True
    get_products.short_description = "Product ---  Price"

class Product(models.Model):
    products = models.CharField(max_length=256, null =True)
    price_for_each_item = models.FloatField(verbose_name = "Price")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.products
```

Comment: why are you creating new profiles for asking questions ?

Comment: Was hoping to get this solved tonight since there is a 6 limit per 24 hour period :/

Comment: fair enough. Can you not just create a `def get_product_prices()` and display it exactly the saame way as `get_products` ?

Comment: Hmmm, but how would the program know that I want the price for each indivual ManyToMany product? Perhaps I am overthinking this...

Comment: Actually, you do not display many to many fields in the list_display in most cases. If you want to do it, you can always override the template that renders the list_display to cater to your needs

Comment: Still really new to Django and haven't messed with templating that much. Would something like this work?  def get_product_prices(self):
                 return "<BR> </BR>" .join "%s" % p.price_for_each_item for p in self.product.all()

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35040/discussion-between-mdjon26-and-karthikr)

Comment: Just build 2 readonly fields, one for products, one for prices. It will be inefficient though.